# How to charge a trash bag

Tags: electrostatics

I needed to come up with something to cover the windows so I can sleep in daylight. I heard trash bags are good, so I just bought some black trash bags and to my surprise, they just sticked to the surface of the windows held by electrostatic force.

They were really charged up, I think it comes from being separated from each other, the same way a tape is charged up when you unroll it.

Now the problem is when I take them down, and apply again, the bags are not as charged up and don't stick to the windows so well.

I tried to charge it by repeatedly hitting/swiping it with my hand (up to down) (sorry for my English here), as well as swiping it against a blanket. I wanted to charge it up more, but it only decreased it (but it was still charged).

What would be some good method of charging it? If I rolled the bags again all together and then started to separate them again, would that work? Or is it just a one time thing?

Comment: Sleeping during daylight hours (shift work I presume) and needing to block out the light - have you tried anything as mundane as *curtains* ?  It is what they are designed for.  They also look better than plastic bags.  And, yes, I have had to sleep in daylight hours.  You can also try a [sleep mask](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sleep+mask&t=lm&ia=images&iax=images) - commonly used on e.g. aircraft long haul flights.  Electrostatically charging a plastic bag is just being a bit [Heath-Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) for my taste, :-)

Comment: It's a place I rent for just 3 weeks. It seems like adding some water on the windows will hold them in place, but I would need to wait and see for how long.

Comment: Blu-tack would maybe be an option or masking tape.  Keep it simple.  Water may cause other problems (e.g. mold, which the landlord might charge you for).